# Full outer join acting like inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I expect the SQL below to return 3 records; but it returns only 2. I expect a row with the following details to be returned, but it's not:

I expect a row with Description Id = 21 to render, and in that row all the columns that begin with "part" should have NULL values.

The two records which are output are correct. The FULL OUTER JOIN seems to be acting like an inner join in terms of which rows it will return, but it properly returns a row where the description on a part and category are returned in one row (Description Ids 18 and 20).

A visual representation of my actual and expected results can be seen here:
https://ibb.co/Vq9GWLw
The first two rows of my actual and desired results are the same. My desired results also includes the record where the part's category has a description, but the part does not have its own description whose Code (9) matches the code of the description associated with the Category.

```
create table Temp.Part (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id asc),
    CategoryId int not null
)

create table Temp.Category (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id asc)
)

create table Temp.Description (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id asc),
    Code int not null,
    Value nvarchar(200) not null
)

create table Temp.DescriptionLink (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id asc),
    EntityId int not null,
    DescriptionId int not null
)
go

declare @partId int = 1
declare @categoryId int = 15

insert into Temp.Category values (@categoryId)
insert into Temp.Part values (@partId, @categoryId)

-- descriptions directly on part
insert into Temp.Description values (17, 6, 'This should output: desc #1 on Part')
insert into Temp.DescriptionLink values (50, @partId, 17)

insert into Temp.Description values (18, 4, 'This should output: desc #2 on Part (common)')
insert into Temp.DescriptionLink values (51, @partId, 18)

 -- descriptions on the part's category
insert into Temp.Description values (20, 4, 'This should output: desc #1 on Category (common)')
insert into Temp.DescriptionLink values (70, @categoryId, 20)

insert into Temp.Description values (21, 9, 'This should output: desc #2 on Category')
insert into Temp.DescriptionLink values (71, @categoryId, 21)

-- description not related to part (should not output)
insert into Temp.DescriptionLink values (72, -4, 99)
insert into Temp.Description values (99, 9, 'This should not be in the output because it belongs to a category not assigned to the part')

go

select  partDesc.DescriptionId 'Part Desc Id', catDesc.DescriptionId 'Category''s Description Id',
    partDesc.Value 'part''s desc', catDesc.Value 'Category''s Desc',
    case when partDesc.Code is not null then partDesc.Code else catDesc.Code end 'DescriptionCode'
from
    Temp.Category
    join Temp.Part on Part.CategoryId = Category.Id

    left join (
        select  L.entityId 'PartId', d.Code, d.Id 'DescriptionId', d.Value
        from
            Temp.DescriptionLink L
            join Temp.Description d on d.Id = L.DescriptionId
    ) partDesc on partDesc.PartId = Part.Id

     full outer join (
        select  l2.EntityId 'CategoryId', d2.Code, d2.Id 'DescriptionId', d2.Value
        from    
            Temp.DescriptionLink L2
            join Temp.Description d2 on d2.Id = L2.DescriptionId
    ) catDesc on
        catDesc.Code = partDesc.Code
        and catDesc.CategoryId = Category.Id
where
    Part.Id = 1
```

So what I want is to list all Descriptions related to a part (either directory or indirectly via the Category). When the part and category have a description with the same code, they should display as one row (see the second row of my sample actual output: https://ibb.co/Vq9GWLw).

Comment: Provide a [mre] with emphasis on *minimal*, including sample data and desired results. Not many people are going to try and make sense of that monstrosity of a query - especially not without sample data to illustrate what is going on.

Comment: Put the `WHERE` conditions into the respective `ON` conditions.

Comment: @Charlieface I can't because the inner query can't refer to table Category.

Comment: Move `Part.Id = 1302860` to the `ON` clause of `Part`, and move `catDesc.CategoryId = Category.Id` to the `ON` of `catDesc`. Sample data for all tables, as well as expected results, would help us understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Charlieface If I move `catDesc.CategoryId = Category.Id` to the ON Clause it means it won't always be applied (FULL outer join after all) I need that condition to always be applied to the final results. I will create sample data when I've free time, just preparing for work.

Comment: WHERE Part.Id = 1302860
 AND ISNULL(catDesc.CategoryId, Category.Id) = ISNULL(Category.Id, catDesc.CategoryId);

Comment: @DaleK SQL added with my expectations of which record should render but does not. Does this help?

Comment: So what is your expected result? Can you show it in some kind of tablular format, and/or explain the steps involved, because I can't understand how the joins are supposed to work. Do you perhaps just want this result? https://dbfiddle.uk/_2jnzakv

Comment: @Charlieface the post now says my expectations. If you want a visual example, I can provide it, but I don't suppose I can add that in stack?

Comment: @Charlieface This image shows my desired output: https://ibb.co/Vq9GWLw   In the past when I've linked to 3rd party sites showing reference images people have complained. The first 2 rows from my desired output and actual output are the same. In the desired output note that it also has a record where the category has a description but the part does not have a Description with the same DescriptionCode.

Comment: That data structure is broken. There is nothing to prevent a description for part 1 also linking to category 1. Do you actually also have a column in the link table to specify what entity TYPE it relates to?

Comment: @MatBailie it's a small sample that's to the point, can you help with the query?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/qyJezuGB

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out what you *actually* want, after much to-ing and fro-ing.

You want to take the join of `DescriptionLink` `Description` `Category`, and Full-Join it to the join of `DescriptionLink` `Description` `Part`.

The join between `Part` and `Category` should *separately* filter those two sets.

So the full logic goes like this:

- Take each `Part` row.
- Cross-apply the following set to each row:

  - take the join of `DescriptionLink` `Description` where the `DescriptionLink.EntityId` refers to the outer `Part.Id`.
  - Take the join of `DescriptionLink` `Description` `Category` where that `Category.Id` is the same as the outer `Part.CategoryId`.
  - Full-join these two together, by `Code`.

Note the use of nested `FULL JOIN ... JOIN ... ON ... ON ...` clauses, in order to full-join the *join result* in each case. You can use `()` parentheses around the joins if you like, it does not make any difference.

```sql
SELECT
  d.*
FROM Temp.Part p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      pd.Id [Part Desc Id],
      cd.Id [Categorys Description Id],
      pd.Value [parts desc],
      cd.Value [Categorys Desc],
      ISNULL(pd.Code, cd.Code) DescriptionCode
    FROM (
        Temp.DescriptionLink pl
        JOIN Temp.Description pd
          ON pd.Id = pl.DescriptionId
         AND p.Id = pl.entityId   -- outer reference
    )
    FULL JOIN (
        Temp.DescriptionLink cl
        JOIN Temp.Description cd
          ON cd.Id = cl.DescriptionId
        JOIN Temp.Category c
            ON c.Id = cl.EntityId
           AND c.Id = p.CategoryId   -- outer reference
    ) ON cd.Code = pd.Code
) d
ORDER BY
  d.DescriptionCode;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/SEFEZJnp)

Note that the `DescriptionLink` table has two major design flaws:

- There is no discriminator column indicating *which type* of entity to join, so in theory there could be joins across both `Part` and `Category`.
- It has a separate primary key. In a many-many join table, you should just have a composite primary key of both foreign keys `(EntityId, DescriptionId)`.

Comment: The join between part and category is relevant because I only want to list Descriptions directly associated to the part, or to that part's category. Imagine instead of "Category" it was "Brand". I want to see all Descriptions for that part, and all Descriptions for the part's brand. So if the part is say "McNuggets", the brand might be McDonalds. The Description might be marketing info, so it might speak about the specific product and also about the brand in general.

Comment: I agree on the composite key, but that was not my choice.

Comment: That's not what you show in your screenshot. If that were the case then an inner-join on those columns would have worked. What you are showing is the results from the category descriptions and the part descriptions, joined *only* by `Code`. If you want something else, I suggest you *very clearly* describe what results you would like, taking into account all edge cases, and describe in words what the logic is.

Comment: Putting it another way, how can the third row have nulls in it if you are joining by `Part`? what possible joining logic could induce that?

Comment: @charlieface I'm not sure what you mean. The part might not have direct descriptions, but I still want to see the descriptions for that part's category (if there are any).

Comment: @Charlieface Do you see how the first record shows the part's description which has no matching category description for the same DescriptionCode? Well I want the opposite also, I want the part's category's Description even if the part doesn't provide its own Description with the same description code.

Comment: So maybe like @MatBailie 's solution? Or without requerying `Part` you can use a `CROSS APPLY` https://dbfiddle.uk/quOQUjyf

Comment: Because the NULLs just say that no DescriptionLink.EntityId points to that part where the DescriptionCode is the same as the Category's Description that is attached to the part. ie: I have a Description on a category where the Description code is 9, but there is no Description whose EntityId is the part where the Description code is 9.

Comment: Your fiddle output is what I expect, but I don't get the same results (I still get 2 rows) when I run your query against my DB. Did you change the data? At a glance it looked the same.

Comment: Oh. ya, I get two rows. I don't get the row where [Categorys Description Id] = 21 using your SQL at your posted fiddle link.

Comment: Can't help you with that. It works in the fiddle with your data https://dbfiddle.uk/quOQUjyf

Comment: is your "ON cd.Code = pd.Code" for the FULL join? I didn't realize you could join and not provide the ON clause for that join until after you've done other joins.

Comment: Yes that is exactly my point. It might be a bit clearer with brackets but I personally find it messy https://dbfiddle.uk/HGm00iwL